# How to dispaly result list into TableLayout row in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

I have a little bit problem that displaying list data to TextView in Android. My scenario is I have a **TableLayout** with Default One **TableRow**. Inside table row, I has been created new **LinearLayout**. Then, Four **TextView** created inside **LinearLayout**. I adding some default value to this textview. My default value is

> 1, 2014-02-05, S02, 20

Here my code snippet for above scenari0.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/sync_history_table_color"
        android:id="@+id/history_table"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >    
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/row_start">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" android:id="@+id/row_linear" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/isp_home_color">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="@string/sync_default_no"
                      android:id="@+id/history_display_no" android:layout_weight="0.165"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                      android:textColor="@color/sync_history_text_color"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:text="@string/sync_default_date"
                      android:id="@+id/history_display_date"
                      android:layout_weight="0.5"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:textColor="@color/sync_history_text_color"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/sync_default_order"
                    android:id="@+id/history_display_orderid"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/sync_history_text_color"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/sync_default_qty"
                    android:id="@+id/history_display_quantity" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/sync_history_text_color"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Actually, I want to create dynamically **TableRow**, **LinearLayout** and **TextView**. Then, I put the list result to add these. The list result come from sqlite db. But, I can't get what I want. Here my code for looping the list and display the result. But, I got my **some default value**. Please pointing to me how can I get this. Thanks.

Here snippet for display list.

```
public void displayHistory(){
    List<IspHistoryListObject> historyList = sqlaccess.getAllItems();
    TableLayout showRow = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.history_table);
    int count = 0;
    for(IspHistoryListObject hl : historyList) {
        count++;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,30));
        TextView tv_sync_no = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_sync_date = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_sync_orderid = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv_sync_qty = new TextView(this);
        tv_sync_no.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        tv_sync_date.setText(hl.getSyncDate().substring(0,10));
        tv_sync_orderid.setText(hl.getSyncOrderIdRef());
        tv_sync_qty.setText(String.valueOf(hl.getQty()));
        ll.addView(tv_sync_no);
        ll.addView(tv_sync_date);
        ll.addView(tv_sync_orderid);
        ll.addView(tv_sync_qty);
        tr.addView(ll);
        showRow.addView(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use `ListView` for this.

Comment: i don't get where the issue , you set the default value in layout and won't display them in code ???

Comment: @mohammed momn Actually, when I don't get null value form sqlite, I want to show default value. I want to  create dynamically this layout.

Comment: so as i understand to need to remove first linear (default) if you have data in cursor ?

Comment: I think, I should try with ListView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way here I gave sample or demo code you have to modify as per your requirement and still have problem let me know

**main layout**

**1. table.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</TableLayout>
```

**table row layout**

**2. table_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/history_display_no"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/history_display_date"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/history_display_orderid"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/history_display_quantity"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</TableRow>
```

**activity class**

**3. Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            View tableRow = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_item,null,false);
            TextView history_display_no  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.history_display_no);
            TextView history_display_date  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.history_display_date);
            TextView history_display_orderid  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.history_display_orderid);
            TextView history_display_quantity  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.history_display_quantity);

            history_display_no.setText(""+(i+1));
            history_display_date.setText("2014-02-05");
            history_display_orderid.setText("S0"+(i+1));
            history_display_quantity.setText(""+(20+(i+1)));
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes bro. Your demo code is really helpful. I got this.

Answer (score 1):

check out context hierachy

```
for(IspHistoryListObject hl : historyList) {
    count++;
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(showRow.getContext());
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(tr.getContext());
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,30));
    TextView tv_sync_no = new TextView(ll.getContext());
    TextView tv_sync_date = new TextView(ll.getContext());
    TextView tv_sync_orderid = new TextView(ll.getContext());
    TextView tv_sync_qty = new TextView(ll.getContext());
    tv_sync_no.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    tv_sync_date.setText(hl.getSyncDate().substring(0,10));
    tv_sync_orderid.setText(hl.getSyncOrderIdRef());
    tv_sync_qty.setText(String.valueOf(hl.getQty()));
    ll.addView(tv_sync_no);
    ll.addView(tv_sync_date);
    ll.addView(tv_sync_orderid);
    ll.addView(tv_sync_qty);
    tr.addView(ll);
    showRow.addView(tr);
}
```

Comment: post image how ur getting

Comment: Showing up in my first image.

Comment: @K-THIHA how ur expecting it to come on the screen

Answer (score 0):

With listview you can easily do this:

ActivityMain.java

```
ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
lst.addHeaderView(header);
lst.setAdapter(new CustomerListAdapter(this,4));
```

list_header.xml is header layout