# How to display data from a database in a table?

Tags: android, database

I'm new to Android Studio and can't seem to find what I'm asking for.
I want to have a database that stores the data of a few people, e.g.

> Steve Hardy, 16 Somewhere Land, Colorado, U.S.A.

I would like this to have headings (Name, Address, City, Country).
I'm just struggling with how to format a table like this and how I would link a database to this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569324/6891637) for the layout

Comment: Hey Milbert, In this forum helps to fix the bug what you tried on your part, So please share the code, Don't lose hope for negative votes. If your question is valid, everyone appreciates you.

Answer (score 0):

In android, mostly use sqlite databases. I can give you 3 simple functions I use to create database and table, insert data to table, & to read database values. If there is any unclear thing or you want any clarification, ask. I can help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Assign below 3 variables as global variables where class start. 

     SQLiteDatabase db; //Assign as a global variable
     String DBName = "MyDB"; //Assign as a global variable
     String TableName = "PeopleData"; //Assign as a global variable

//Call 3 function inside oncreate method.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       createDB_Table(); //calling 3 functions.
       InsertDataToDB();
       ReadDBData();        
            }

public void createDB_Table(){ //This function use to create database, table & columns.
             db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Address TEXT, City TEXT, Country TEXT);");        
             db.close();
                            }

public void InsertDataToDB(){ //This function use to inset values to database.
           db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
           ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();       
           cv.put("Name","Steve Hardy");
           cv.put("Address","16 Somewhere Land");
           cv.put("City","Colorado");
           cv.put("Country","USA");
           db.insert(TableName, null, cv);
           db.close();
                            }

public void ReadDBData() { //This function use to read data from database.
             db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
             Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, null);

      if (cursor.getCount() > 0) { //check cursor is not empty.
        cursor.moveToFirst();        
        String DName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        String DAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address"));
        String DCity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("City"));
        String DCountry = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Country"));  
    //Got the values from database. Then you can set those values to text view or something you use.                            
                                  }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
                            }
        }
```